# Press button and Send Message Error

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, button

The problem is that sometime I don't even need to press the button and it sent message and keep on sending continuously.

What I want to do is that once the button is pressed, sent 1 message.

I cannot figure out why it is happening. Please help me to figure out.

```
 #define CUSTOM_SETTINGS
    #define INCLUDE_GPS_SHIELD
    #define INCLUDE_SMS_SHIELD
    #define INCLUDE_VIBRATION_SHIELD

/* Include 1Sheeld library.*/
#include <OneSheeld.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SW 8


/* Define a boolean flag. */

float lat;
float lon;
String Message;
String Message1;
String Message2;
char latitude[10];
char longitude[10];


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(SW, INPUT);
  /* Start communication.*/
  Serial.begin(9600);
  OneSheeld.begin();

}

void Emergency() {

      /* Send SMS. */
      if(digitalRead(SW) == 1)
      {  
        lat = GPS.getLatitude();
        lon = GPS.getLongitude();
        Message1 = String(lat,8);
        Message2 = String(lon,8);

        Message = "I need Help! Google Maps - https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/" + Message1 + "," + Message2;
        Serial.println(Message);

        SMS.send("0637200721",Message);
        //Vibration.start(1000,2000);

        delay(3000);
      }
}

void loop()
{ 
  Emergency();

  delay(1000);
}
```

This is how I connect the button. The Grey cable is for Ground, The red is for 5V and the orange is to pin8. Between Red and Grey there is resistor.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a coding answer for you, but your problem is almost certainly contact bounce. There are de-bounce settings, but these tend to be one-way. A better approach is to detect a press, delay for a short time then confirm the button is still pressed.

Comment: @Milliways I am quite new to this field. So can you advice me more how to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of references e.g. https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/SoftwareDebounce

Comment: I am trying to puzzle out the wiring of your button. It looks like you have +5V -> Resistor -> GND and then also GPIO  -> GND, and alongside that Nothing -> Button -> GND. Learn how to wire a button!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is because I didn't put the following lines and I changed to use physical push button to 1Sheeld provided button from mobile. The follwing is the working code.

```
#define CUSTOM_SETTINGS
#define INCLUDE_GPS_SHIELD
#define INCLUDE_SMS_SHIELD
#define INCLUDE_VIBRATION_SHIELD
#define INCLUDE_PUSH_BUTTON_SHIELD

/* Include 1Sheeld library.*/
#include <OneSheeld.h>
#include <string.h>


/* Define a boolean flag. */
boolean isMessageSent = false;
float lat;
float lon;
String Message;
String Message1;
String Message2;
char latitude[10];
char longitude[10];


void setup() 
{
  /* Start communication.*/
  Serial.begin(9600);
  OneSheeld.begin();
  PushButton.setOnButtonStatusChange(&Emergency);
}

void loop()
{ 

}


void Emergency(byte isButtonPressed) {
 if(isButtonPressed)
      {  
        if(!isMessageSent)
        lat = GPS.getLatitude();
        lon = GPS.getLongitude();
        Message1 = String(lat,8);
        Message2 = String(lon,8);

        Message = "I need Help! Google Maps - https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/" + Message1 + "," + Message2;
        Serial.println(Message);

        SMS.send("0637200721",Message);
        isMessageSent = true; // This line 
      }
      else{
        isMessageSent = false; // This line
      }
```